# How do i paste some line text don't error on Android

Tags: java, android, error-handling, line, textview

I'm developing a story app.

I have some line text like:

A: Hello

B: Hi

A: How are you?

B: I'm fine

And paste it at 
TextView.setText("A: Hello

B: Hi

A: How are you?

B: I'm fine");

i met error each line and must fix each line
TextView.setText("A: Hello"+

"\nB: Hi"+

"\nA: How are you?"+

"\nB: I'm fine");

So i want to ask how can i paste some line text like above at TextView.setText(""); don't have this error? Or i have to fix each line?
Thanks for read!

Comment: TextView.append("A: Hello");  TextView.append("\n");  TextView.setText("B: Hi"); TextView.append("\n");...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .java

```
textView1.setText(R.string.conversation1);
```

in string.xml

```
<string name="conversation1">"A: Hello\nB: Hi\nA: How are you?\nB: I'm fine"</string>
```